# Проблемы с recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, разметка

Добрый день. Пишем приложение под андроид, появилась надобность сделать профиль, а под профилем ленту. По сути, сделали, но есть одно но. Приложение у нас с вкладками (ну знаете, такие на верху, можно вправо/влево пальцем елозить и переключаться между фрагментами). Так вот, есть у нас фрагмент профиля (грубо говоря, разметка верхняя часть профиля, там, где всякая информация о пользователе (подписчики, статус и тп, представьте себе профиль инстаграмма, стену вк в мобильном приложении). Сначала "голова" профиля, а под ним лента). далее. лента у нас выводится карточками. т.е. есть специальная xml заготовка и вот она выводится под "головой" нужное кол-во раз. и по сути то, все работает, но список  не двигается по инерции после попытки пролистнуть. Т.е. нельзя тупо провести пальцем по экрану, чтобы оно дальше само листало. Далее есть у нас сама лента (не профиль с записями) там никакой "головы" нет и все работает отлично.

Comment: Это не плавный скрол, а иннерция скрола. Плавный скрол - это когда при скроле не дергается содержимое. А у вас нету иннерции в `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @metalurgus да, вы правы

Comment: Ну так отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал вашей проблеме.

Comment: @metalurgus теперь не плохо бы по поводу проблемы услышать

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю ,как исправить. Нашел только баг репорт: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196584

Comment: Укажите хоть какие-то данные. Например я могу предположить, что у вас стоит самая последняя версия библиотеки, и в ней может содержаться баг.
Если ткнуть вслепую, попробуйте сменить версию библиотеки поддержки(и recyclerview + cardview библиотеки в том числе) на 23.3.0

Comment: @Asgard товарищ сказал, что я не правильно задал вопрос. Вот его вопрос :) "Проблема в том, что нельзя использовать ресайклер вью внутри скрол вью) Нужно было задать так: как прикрепить к ресайклер вью слой с другими вьюэлементами?"